# Insert values from database to xml table and output them with ajax in html

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, xml

I have a search box where user can type in a name and it will display `"firstname", "username", "lastname", "email", "accountnumber"`. So far I have been able to get the data from database, make xml structure of it (it was one of the requirements in the school). The question is how can I echo the values that come from search box into the xml table and then output the result into the HTML table?

Code for the database (file is called ajax-search.php): (I know I am using mysql and I will fix that later)

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/xml");
//Create Database connection
$db = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select the Database
mysql_select_db("bank",$db);

$sSearchFor = $_GET['sSearchFor'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%$sSearchFor%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());

//Create SimpleXMLElement object
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');


//Add each column value a node of the XML object

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $mydata = $xml->addChild('mydata');
    $mydata->addChild('Id',$row['id']);
    $mydata->addChild('Name',$row['name']);
    $mydata->addChild('user_name',$row['user_name']);
    $mydata->addChild('last_name',$row['last_name']);
    $mydata->addChild('email',$row['email']);
    $mydata->addChild('account_number',$row['account_number']);

}

//Create the XML file
$fp = fopen("employeeData.xml","a+");

//$fp = fopen("php://output","a+");

//Write the XML nodes
fwrite($fp,$xml->asXML()."\r\n" );

//Close the database connection
fclose($fp);

mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Code for the xml, (file is called xmltable.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchresults>
  <name>test</name>
  <username>test</username>
  <lastname>test</lastname>
  <email>test.test@gmail.com</email>
  <accountnumber>93207802685726</accountnumber>
</searchresults>
```

And the final script for the ajax is on the index page:

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
    var sSearchFor = $("#txtSearch").val();
    var searchLink = "ajax-search.php?sSearchFor=" + sSearchFor;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xmltable.xml",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('searchresults').each(function () {
                $(this).find("name").each(function () {
                    var name = $(this).text();
                    alert(name);
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I appreciate all the help since I am really lost right now.

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_GET` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the tips. I am aware of th SQL injection and will remove/ improve my answer once i get it to work.

Comment: It really shouldn't be there in the first place. PDO makes it very easy to write queries without those problems. As always when debugging code like this, keep your JavaScript console open all the time. That's the only way to spot scripting errors. Keep tabs on the Network traffic as well, especially the response from your PHP code.

Comment: @tadman will do sir! appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

### Cient side:

You forgot to add *searchLink* in your url!

```
    $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
    var searchLink = "ajax-search.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: searchLink,
        data: {sSearchFor : $("#txtSearch").val() },
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('searchresults').find('result').each(function () {
                var name = $(this).find("name").text();
                alert(name);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

### Server side:

Use this on your .PHP file. I've commented the lines that deal with file saving:

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/xml");
//Create Database connection
$db = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select the Database
mysql_select_db("bank",$db);

if(isset($_POST['sSearchFor']))
    $sSearchFor = $_POST['sSearchFor'];
else
    $sSearchFor = "";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%$sSearchFor%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());

//Create SimpleXMLElement object
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('searchresults');


//Add each column value a node of the XML object

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $result= $xml->addChild('result');
    $result->addChild('id',$row['id']);
    $result->addChild('name',$row['name']);
    $result->addChild('username',$row['user_name']);
    $result->addChild('lastname',$row['last_name']);
    $result->addChild('email',$row['email']);
    $result->addChild('accountnumber',$row['account_number']);
}

// You can close BD now
mysql_close($db);

//Create the XML file
//$fp = fopen("employeeData.xml","a+");

//$fp = fopen("php://output","a+");

//Write the XML nodes
//fwrite($fp,$xml->asXML()."\r\n" );

//Close file
//fclose($fp);

echo $xml->asXML();

?>
```

Hope it helps and good luck!

Comment: I've edited my answer. If it doesn't work, let me know the errors/behaviour.
Also, you should test if the variable $_POST['sSearchFor'] is set (using isset function).
Test only the .PHP file to see if the XML is being generated correctly. If so, test the client side request.

Comment: If I test the php file, I get this error: "error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document" this appears as soon as I add your provided code.

Comment: Edited again. Use my file instead. I don't have a http server app installed so I can't quite test PHP but that should do.
(I don't know if you get notified when I edit my answer)